# Using ng-options for a select field inside an ng-repeat how do I filter out previously selected values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I am creating a select dropdown that can dynamically be added by the user. Clicking a button will execute the following line: `"$scope.expenses.push({});"` adding a new select dropdown to the page for them to choose from.

This piece is working perfectly fine. But I am running into the issue of the user being able to select the same item in both fields. I have not been able to successfully filter out any other selected values from the dropdown fields. Any pointers would be lovely!

I'm thinking either a custom filter to hide the other selected values or an ng-change function to update the array I am looping over..

Here is my current code:

```
<div ng-repeat="expense in expenses track by $index">
    <label for="itemDescr_{{$index + 1}}">${item_descr}</label>
    <select id="itemDescr_{{$index + 1}}" name="itemDescr_{{$index + 1}}" ng-model="expenses[$index].ItemCode" ng-class="{submitted:submitted}" required ng-options="benefit.Code as benefit.Description for benefit in purchDescOptions | removeUsedItemsFilter | orderBy:'Description'">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is the array ($scope.purchDescOptions) I am looping over:

```
[
    {
        Code:"HOU",
        Description:"Housewares"
    },
    {
        Code:"ATO",
        Description:"Auto Parts, Equipmnt"
    },
    {
        Code:"APP",
        Description:"Appliances"
    },
    {
        Code:"CLO",
        Description:"Clothing"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can u create a fiddle?

Comment: I am a bit down to the wire on this one. I tried creating a fiddle quickly, but I can't seem to get it to work at the moment.